# Pure JavaScript problem with the list of backgrounds

Tags: javascript

I have a list of pictures that I would like to use as a background in my game.
So it is like that

```
var images = [image1.jpg, image2.jpag, image3.jpg]

var randomImagesIndex = getRandom(0, images.length)

box.style.backgroundImage = `url('images[randomImagesIndex]')
```

The result in the Console is like that:

```
bastards[0]:1          GET file:///C:/Users/asouk/Documents/Projects/Trizub/images[0] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

If I try to write directly lije that

box.style.backgroundImage = `url('image1.jpg')

it works! So the images are there. But there brouser does not open it,
it does not change images[0] for example to image1.jpg. If I write something like this

box.style.backgroundImage = `url('images[0]')

I think that my mistake is very simple but I am new to JS and I can not fix it 2 days already.

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Looks like some template literal formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg']

var randomImagesIndex = getRandom(0, images.length)
var image = images[randomImagesIndex]

box.style.backgroundImage = `url('${image}')`
```